# PyQt4 Regarding Class Documentation

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before or not, but I have searched for it a bunch, perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords. I've also googled for it, but I think I'd like a more specific answer.

My question relates to the following line seen in pretty much every PyQt4 class documentation

> The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt
>   instead of PyQt.
>
> Constructs a dialog with parent parent.
>
> A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its
>   default location is centered on top of the parent. It will also share
>   the parent's taskbar entry.

I want to understand exactly what this means. From what I understand it has to do with how the object lives in memory and how it interacts with Python's garbage collection.

To be a little bit more concrete, say I have a QMainWindow and I pass it as the parent to a QDialog. ie somewhere I have a function like this

```
def ShowFooDialog():
   dlg = FooDialog()
   if dlg.exec_():
      --doSomeStuff--
```

what would be the difference between that and the following

```
def ShowFooDialog():
   dlg = FooDialog(parent=MyMainWindow)
   if dlg.exec_():
      --doSomeStuff--
```

Thanks! If this is something that could have been found out by better reading of the PyQt4 docs I apologize in advance!

Comment: If you won't go into it too deeply(memory-wise), I think the best way to explain it is that the child is destroyed at the latest when the parent is. As the documentation of [QWidget.__init__](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#QObject) states: 'The parent of an object may be viewed as the object's owner. [...] The destructor of a parent object destroys all child objects.'. There are problems in memory management in PyQt though. A fun blog post about it can be found [here](http://ralsina.me/weblog/posts/BB990.html).

Comment: I think I had gotten what you said, but the blog answers something that I was wondering about which is that the second piece of code leaks QDialog objects. Thanks!